# guava: why methods create() instead of constructor?

Tags: java, constructor, guava, static-methods

Please, can you explain why the creators of guava prefer to define the constructors as private, and to define static methods `create()` to create objects ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Effective Java item 1: Consider static factory methods instead of constructors.

Some of the advantages of static factory methods include:

- They automatically infer type parameters pre-Java 7.
- They allow us to control inheritance patterns: we can subclass collection types within Guava without letting outside code subclass them.
- They let us return an arbitrary subclass of the desired type, letting us hide implementation details better.

Comment: Book content is [available online](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/9780137150021/creating-and-destroying-objects/ch02lev1sec1) too.

Comment: I would add the advantage that I find the most important from the end-user point of view: they have a clearer name. `newHashMapWithCapacity(100)` is much clearer than `new HashMap<Foo>(100)`.

Comment: @JBNizet: We do provide those methods for the JDK collection implementations, but for our homegrown collection types we actually don't usually have more detailed factory names than `create`. (I'm not sure that was the right call, of course, for exactly the reason you describe.)

Comment: Thank you very much for these replies, it is much clearer now !